# Google results for my new Wordpress site are showing code for a slider

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I built a site at www.keren.nyc.  The Google result for my site is showing some code from the slider on my site underneath my site URL and tagline.

This is the result:

Keren.nyc | Full Service Web Design
www.keren.nyc/
00:00. Initializing... stage: 320x240 file: http://www.keren.nyc/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/shutterstock_v2512025.mp4 autoplay: false preload: none isvideo: ...

How do I fix this?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: You could try to fix the html errors and see if that fixes it: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.keren.nyc&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

You could download Wordpress SEO by Yoast
Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

This will allow you to manually set the title and description tag.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I actually did just that, but no change.  It's been around 7 hours.

Comment: I think it will update the next time Google crawls your site.
I do not think Google will block your usage of the description tag.

Comment: I am still having this issue, 6 months later.  I have gone through all the Yoast settings, looked at the html errors (which seemed unrelated) and looked into the page source to see if anything was strange with the meta tags.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe adding the site to Google Webmaster could give you some hints. Or force Google to recrawl http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2198245/how-to-force-google-to-recrawl-your-site